# How to plot pct_change for many stock names

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, line-plot

I have a data set with prices of 6 major stocks i.e., Google, Amazon etc.

My plan is to create a plot which would show a percent change, `pct_change()`of column known as `close_value`.

As you can see my `ticker_symbol` is an object. I tried and changed it to float because of the string error but then I lost all ticker names i.e. I executed `returns.close_value.plot();`.

How not to lose stock names while plotting?

[image: Data display]

[image: Pct_change for data set]]

[image: Data info]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Create Sample DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'day_date': ['2020-05-28', '2020-05-27', '2020-05-26', '2020-05-22'], 
                    'ticker_symbol': ['AAPL', 'AAPL','TSLA','TSLA'],
                    'close_value': [318, 400, 500, 450]})

# Convert to Timestamp format
df1['day_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['day_date'])

# Store % Change in new Column
df1['pct_change_close_value'] = df1['close_value'].pct_change()

# Fill null value with 0
df1['pct_change_close_value'].fillna(0, inplace = True)

# Display
display(df1)

# Check Data types of columns
display(df1.dtypes)

# Use Seaborn to plot
sns.lineplot(data = df1, x = 'day_date', y = 'pct_change_close_value', hue = 'ticker_symbol')
```

You just need to set hue = `ticker_symbol` in sns plot.

[image]

Comment: Added under data display link

Comment: @BobMac if this solves your problem, let me know and accept as answer.